# Unable to set value to a lightning:input component

Tags: lightning-web-components

**HTML Template**

```html
<template>
   
   <lightning:card>
    <lightning-button variant="brand"
    label="New Entry"
    title="Open Modal"
    onclick={openModal}
    class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button variant="brand"
    label="Mail"
    title="Open Mail"
    onclick={openMail}
    class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    
    <template if:true={bShowMail}>
      <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
         <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <!-- modal header start -->
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
              
               <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Send Quotation to customer</h2>
            </header>
            <!-- modal body start -->
            <lightning-card>
            <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
  
               <lightning-input label="Enquirer" name="display" type="textarea" value={disName} ></lightning-input> // need to set value here
              <lightning-input label="Recipient mailID" name="recp" type="email" value={recpt} onchange={handleMail} ></lightning-input>
             
     
       <lightning-button label="Send" onclick={handleSend}></lightning-button>
       <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
      
      
             </p>
             </lightning-card>
            <!-- modal footer start-->
          
         </div>
      </section>
   
   </template>







 <!-- modal start -->        
 <template if:true={bShowModal}>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
       <div class="slds-modal__container">
          <!-- modal header start -->
          <header class="slds-modal__header">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                   alternative-text="close"
                   variant="inverse"
                   size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
             </button>
             <h2 id="modal-heading-02" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Quotation</h2>
          </header>
          <!-- modal body start -->
          <lightning-card>
          <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">


            <lightning-input label="Date" name="datefld" type="date" value={fDate} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="Quotation Name" name="enquiry" type="textarea" value={enq} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>
  
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
               <lightning-input-field field-name="Project__c" onchange={projectChange}>
               </lightning-input-field>
               </lightning-record-edit-form>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Unit__c"  onchange={unitChange}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    
    
   <lightning-input label="Unit Rate" name="rate" type="Double" value={rNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Additional cost" name="cost" type="Double" value={cNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Discount" name="dis" type="Double" value={dNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Agreement cost" name="agree" type="Double" value={aNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Remarks" name = "remark" type="textarea" value={resultsum} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input> 
   
     <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    
    
           </p>
           </lightning-card>
          <!-- modal footer start-->
        
       </div>
    </section>
 
 </template>
 <!-- modal end -->
    <h2> Estimation</h2>

    <div if:true={accList}>
        <lightning-datatable data={accList} columns={columns} key-field="Id" onclick={handleclick} >
        </lightning-datatable>
      </div>
    <div if:true={error}>
        {error}
    </div>
  
   </lightning:card>

</template>
```

---

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement , wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.getAccountList';

import sentMail from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.sentMail';

export default class PriceScreen extends LightningElement {
 
 
    @track disName;
  
    @track bShowMail = false;
   
    @track Name;
    @track columns = [
        {  
            label: "Name",  
            fieldName: "recordLink",
            type: "url",  
            typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Name" },  target: "_self" }  
           },
         
    ];

   
    @track error;
    @track accList ;
  
    @wire(getAccountList)
    wiredAccounts({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            var tempOppList = [];  
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                
             let tempRecord = Object.assign({}, data[i]); //cloning object  
             tempRecord.Name = tempRecord.Name;
             tempRecord.recordLink = "/" + tempRecord.Id;  
            
             tempOppList.push(tempRecord);  
            }  
            console.log('hHIIII' + data)
            this.accList = tempOppList;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

      
      
openMail() {
        const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').getSelectedRows();
        const selectedIds = [];
        
        
        // Display that fieldName of the selected rows
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
            console.log("You selected: " + selectedRows[i].Id);
        }

        sentMail({ids: selectedIds}).then(result => {
            this.disName = result;// I need to set this disName to lightning:input having label 'Enquirer'
            console.log("Opps updated!" + result)
             // Display fresh data in the datatable
             this.selectedRows = [];
             return refreshApex(this.wiredDataResult);
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
    }


  
   
    openMail() {    
        // to open modal window set 'bShowModal' tarck value as true
        this.bShowMail = true;
    }
  
}
```

**APEX Controller class**

```java
public with sharing class PriceFetch {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<Price__c> getAccountList() {
        System.debug('HII');
        return [SELECT Id,  Name
            FROM Price__c ];
    }
   
   @AuraEnabled
    public static String sentMail(String[] ids) {

       return [SELECT Enquirer__r.Name 
                 FROM Price__c 
                 WHERE Id in :ids][0].Enquirer__r.Name; 
         
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the HTML code for this "lightning:input"?

Comment: Could you please check now?

Comment: It might be helpful to have some context and a few more details. Like what should I be looking for in all this code. There are a lot of `lightning-input` tags in that template. Which one? What's the behavior? What have you done already to troubleshoot? It can also be more helpful to try to create an excerpt of code that narrows down to just the thing that isn't working.

Comment: Also, one thing I see right off is that your modal window template is using `if:true={bShowModal}` and your js class doesn't have a property called that. But there is one called `bShowMail`. But that doesn't have to do with a `lightning-input` tag.

Comment: Sir, only look the portion <template if:true={bShowMail} >.And there is a lightning button on the top of the HTML Template having label 'Mail'. I am trying to open the <template  if:true={bShowMail} > on the click of this lightning:button. Inside the <template if:true={bShowMail>, there is a lightning:input having label 'Enquirer'. I am trying to set value to this field. On the lightning:button('Mail') click, the selected rows of lightning:datatable are passed to the sentMail() method in apex controller class, and the method return the name, and it is set to the 'disName'

Comment: <lightning-input label="Enquirer" name="display" type="textarea" value={disName} ></lightning-input>

Comment: @Athira Venugopal, In the sentMail event why you set prefix this of property selectedRows ? Check your syntax this.selectedRows = []; What Is your result console out?